# Referencing App.config file through a .NET class library DLL in ColdFusion 9

Tags: .net, dll, coldfusion, app-config, c#-5.0

I'm currently developing DLLs in .NET that use Entity Framework to access our database.

It is my understanding that DLLs do not have ties with the same App.config files as exe applications do. Through a good amount of research, I have learned that DLLs  do not contain App.config and are best left agnostic(config) so the program using the DLL can determine the config.

I'm receiving this error and am sure that the connection string is defined in my app.config:

**System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the application config file.**

I'm positive that I would like the config file to always be the same DLL and would appreciate any suggestions that may point me towards "best practices" in achieving this implementation.

Thanks in advance,

Russ

Comment: I'm not sure this appropriately has anything to do with CF.

Comment: I don't know how to do it.  I am not sure that it can be done because ColdFusion does not use config files the same way .net does.  It also doesn't use connection strings the way .net does.  Having said all that, maybe this will help.  https://code.google.com/p/configcfc/

Comment: I don't know ColdFusion but I know how App.config works. What you said, " ...DLLs do not have ties with the same App.config files as exe applications do" is incorrect. It works the same. app.config loads with running application in form of application_name.exe.config. You can have config sections in development, in the app.config in your class library [dll] project. But for the runtime, you need to copy it into app.config that will be loaded in context of your application. You can keep them separately too. But then you need to provide link from top app.config to your ddl-related app.config

Comment: You are writing DLLs in .NET that use a framework to access your database and want to use these DLLs from within ColdFusion? Is there a reason why you don't use ColdFusion to talk directly to the database? The way you explain seems very Rube Goldberg-ish.

Comment: Scott. I wasn't clear on why we are doing this, but the goal is to gradually replace coldFusion legacy code piece by piece so we can gradually move the application to ASP.NET.