# .NET Entity Framework .dll consumed by coldfusion 9

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, coldfusion

I have a .NET Entity Framework Data Library .dll that I was hoping to consume with a coldfusion web app. everything works except the .dll is expecting the app.config to have the `connectionstring` for the entities. obviously coldfusion doesn't use the web.config (it's IIS hosted) and/or an `app.config` like a .net web app does.

Is there a way to make this work? I've put the connection string information inside the web.config as well as inside the app.config of the .dll that connects to the database. neither of these have worked.

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="TestCFEntry" class="TestCFEntryPoint.CFEntryPoint" assembly="d:/path/to/dll/TestClass.dll">
```

The error I'm receiving is.

> No connection string named 'blahblahDataEntities' could be found in
>   the application config file.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Added code snippet

Comment: How are you consuming with ColdFusion app? Could you share the code snippet?

Comment: Edit: added code snippet.

Comment: if I remove the entity framework aspect of the .dll everything works as expected.

Comment: Seem similar to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494015/referencing-app-config-file-through-a-net-class-library-dll-in-coldfusion-9
You can check the link provided by Dan in the comment.

Comment: I found this post http://mumblestiltskin.blogspot.in/2012/01/coldfusion-901-native-iis-7-support.html This may help.

Comment: Nothing I tried worked...I ended up just hard coding the location of the config file in the .net code and putting the connectionstring in there to solve my issue.